# In (Crux Magi) VSF report

Tags: star-magi

> “It’s ruined, sir. There’s nothing left. No life signs. Nothing.” Aris glanced at the scan officer sat at his station on the VSF Rampart as he reported his findings to Admiral Orlan.

Aris glanced at scan officer who is sat at his station on the VSF Rampart reporting to to Admiral Orlan (who is also on the VSF?) the VSF is a small ship?

Answer (score 0):

The VSF Rampart is described as being "*vast*", at least in comparison to the ships used by the rest of humanity.

> Aris felt the shift in the momentum of the ship beneath his feet as
> the boosters fired up and the ship moved off. Around them, Valk ships
> moved to escort them as they flew through the system. T**hey were soon
> on final approach to a vast capital ship and proceeded to land in one
> of its docking bays.** They had been escorted here the whole time and
> even now felt like they were being watched.
>
> <sub><sup>MAGI NEXUS</sup></sub>

The acronym VSF refers to '***Valk Space Force***'.

> They floated in the void, the flagship, the **Valk Space Force Rampart**, a short distance below them. Around the flagship, other Valk ships were closing in on it, responding to her appearance on the bridge.
>
> <sub><sup>MAGI NEXUS</sup></sub>

For the record, the bridge of the VSF Rampart appears to comprise around ten crewmen and officers. They are variously referred to by their positions (e.g Helm, Scan, Comms, etc.) rather than being given names by the author.

---

At the point in the book that you're referencing, Admiral Orlan is situated aboard the Rampart with his aide Sulvan, which is to be expected given that the Rampart is the fleet's flagship (e.g. literally the ship that carries the [flag officer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_officer)).

> As Aris watched the room from his usual guard station at the back, he
> caught Sulvan’s eye who nodded to him. He wondered if Sulvan felt the
> same about the threat of the Crux. If he didn’t, this might be the
> turning point for him, as well.
>
> The burn across the system didn’t take long, and as the ship cut its
> Displacement Drive, it slowed as a rocky planet shot out of the dark.
>
> “What am I looking at here?” Orlan asked. It wasn’t obvious what was
> going on from the viewscreen.
>
> <sub><sup>CRUX MAGI</sup></sub>